# Composer autoload file not work if set in repositories

Tags: php, cakephp, package, composer-php

i wrote the followings

```
"repositories": [{
  "type": "package",
  "package": {
    "name": "rysas/ffxiv-lodestone-php-api",
    "version": "dev-master",
    "source": {
      "url": "git://github.com/rysas/Final-Fantasy-XIV-Lodestone-PHP-API.git",
      "type": "git",
      "reference": "origin/master"
    },
    "autoload": {
      "files": [
        "vendor/rysas/ffxiv-lodestone-php-api/ffxiv-lodestone-api.php"
      ]
    }
  }
}]
```

After doing a composer update, my library isn't loaded, everything works fine if i do the following

```
"repositories": [{
  "type": "package",
  "package": {
    "name": "rysas/ffxiv-lodestone-php-api",
    "version": "dev-master",
    "source": {
      "url": "git://github.com/rysas/Final-Fantasy-XIV-Lodestone-PHP-API.git",
      "type": "git",
      "reference": "origin/master"
    }
  }
}],
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
    "App\\": "src"
  },
  "files": [
    "vendor/rysas/ffxiv-lodestone-php-api/ffxiv-lodestone-api.php"
  ]
}
```

Do i really need to declare the autoloader ouside of the declaration of my package ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add package information as "type=package", you have to do that from the perspective of that package.

And the autoloading rules say that autoloading must be defined relative from the PACKAGE ROOT. The package root is the directory that gets placed at "vendor/*vendorname*/*packagename*/", i.e. you must not add either the directory "vendor", "rysas" and "ffxiv-lodestone-php-api" to the autoload definition path.

Additionally, you should not use the "files" autoloader if the code that needs to get autoloaded is in fact a PHP class. Use the classmap autoloader for that (you can point it at distinct files as well as directories). The difference: Classmap autoloading takes place only if the class is needed. Files autoloading isn't really automatic - the files is ALWAYS executed when you require "vendor/autoload.php".

Files autoloading is meant to add global functions outside of classes because PHP cannot autoload them. The better solution for such code would be to put them into a class as a static function - this can be autoloaded. It should be seen as a workaround for old legacy code to make it usable with Composer.

Comment: I undestand my mistake about classmap/files, and i have changed this. Composer doc say : https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2. So why i'm unable to reproduce the same for my package about autoloader ?

Comment: Look at the classmap path in the example you linked. It is "libs/", not "vendor/smarty/smarty/libs".

Comment: Yeah, but doc on CakePHP 3 confuse me : http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files. It is vendor/vendorname/packagename

Comment: Read the text around it. First of all, they deal with the issue of a package not being usable via Packagist. They tell something of "install it yourself", then add an autoloading to make up for the lack of Composer support from that package. They explicitly do not define a "type=package" replacement. So they do something different than you do, they are doing it the way your second attempt is done. You shouldn't do it like that. In fact, creating a github account, cloning the original repository, adding a `composer.json` file yourself and registering it at packagist.org probably is easier.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and I think it's composer bug, because, I added 2 packages using this approach and one work without adding any autoload clause outside the package but to make the second work I should do what the question is showing.
If I go to the vendor package folder and do `composer dump-autoload`, the files autoload setting is being loaded, but the same command executed at the app level doesn't work, composer doesn't know anything about the package add.